# Desktop Publisher (Alternatives to InDesign)

Tags: open-source, graphic-design, desktop-publishing

[Adobe InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/au/products/indesign.html) is the dominant player in the Desktop Publishing world.
It is used for many books, and also for magazine and pamphlets, and even things like greeting-cards and invitations.

It is almost $1000, and having used it, if I were in the business of professionally producing books, (esp, with complex layouts), I would say it would be worth every penny.
How ever, at the moment I'm only doing it as a hobby.

It's lower-end cousin is MS-Publisher, which can be replaced with [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus).
(Feel free to answer with a argument that suggests Scribus can replace InDesign)

[conTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page), a cousin of LaTeX seems like it might be a alternative,
but the learning curve seems steep (the few times I've tried).

LaTeX itself might be a good alternative, but it seem that it forces you into the mould of what ever document class you are using (eg memoir, koma-book), and that to define a document-class of your own, you need far more than beginner knowledge.

---

### Important Features

- Must be [Desktop Publishing Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_publishing), not word processing, not website design.
- Must support kerning
- Must support advance Open type features: Ligatures, Swash/Titling/Contextual alternatives.
- Should have support for [structured document data import/templating](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS372C59DB-BD13-4806-A399-794E754FF37Aa.html) (Thus allowing separation of presentation from content. (This would be a huge plus for me).
- Should have Mail Merge (which is similar to the structured data import, but simpler)
- Ideally would have better support for OpenType style sets, than InDesign has, but I can live with no support for style sets, as InDesigns support is only just usable.

**Cost/Licence**:
Must be free,
Ideally would be Open Source

**OS**: Any, with slight preference towards Linux > Windows > Mac > OS/2 ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) is an open source desktop publisher.

- Supports [kerning](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Kerning)
- Supports [ligating](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Apply_basic_ligatures_to_a_document)
- Supports templates to separate content from presentation
- It has [a kind of mail merge](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Poor_man%27s_mail_merge)
- Support for font embedding and sub-setting with TrueType, Type 1 and OpenType fonts.

Free and open source.
Runs on Windows, Linux/UNIX, Mac OS X, OS/2 Warp 4/eComStation, FreeBSD, PC-BSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Solaris, OpenIndiana, GNU/Hurd, Haiku.

[image]

Comment: Scribus is still rather limited on Opentype Features. No Contextual alternatives. And the Scribus palette (via insert glyph) cannot even show all glyphs in professional Opentype Fonts: unmapped glyphs (those variants) are not even visible or manually insertable (Nov 2018, Scribus 1.5.4).